# ExpandableListView: inflate childview into parent groupview

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I have an `ExpandableListView` with a custom `CursorTreeAdapter`.
Group row layout has a frame (shape drawable) as background. I would like that child rows appear inside that frame and not below it.
How could I inflate child views inside parent groupview?